# Autodesk Forge Viewer open multiple views together

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I trying to open multiple views of one model in one forge viewer, but every time it opens only one view but two times. I want to know is it possible to open more than one view or I can open together only the different models.

For opening I use this code

```
const svf_path =
      "/storage/" + decodeURIComponent(props.search.split("&&")[1]);

    Autodesk.Viewing.endpoint.getItemApi = (endpoint, derivativeUrn, api) => {
      return svf_path;
    };

Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, async () => {
      if (props.checked_3D_views.length >= 2) {
       
      const path = svf_path.split("/");
      const [dest, svf_dir] = [path[2], path[3]];
      const url = `/api/viewer/dest/${dest}/svf/${svf_dir}/manifest`;

 Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, async () => {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const manifest = await response.json();

const viewer_start = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const model = props.loc_viewer.impl.modelQueue().getModels()[0];
            props.loc_viewer.impl.unloadModel(model);
            const viewerDocument = new Autodesk.Viewing.Document(manifest);
            const viewables = viewerDocument
              .getRoot()
              .search(Autodesk.Viewing.BubbleNode.MODEL_NODE);

            const views = [];

            props.checked_3D_views.map(x => {
              views.push(
                viewables.filter(viewable => viewable.data.name === x.name),
              );
            });

views.forEach((view, index) => {
              resolve(
                props.loc_viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, view[0], {
                  globalOffset: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0},
                }),
              );
            });
          });
          viewer_start.then(() => {
            set_bool(true);
          });
        });
```

I also try to open different models together and it works correctly, but I can't open more than two.
If someone familiar with this kind of problem, please explain to me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `keepCurrentModels` to true as you did for the placementTransform

```
async function addViewable(viewer, urn, xform, offset) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
            const viewable = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
            const options = {
                preserveView: true,
                keepCurrentModels: true //!<<<< You need to set this option to true as you did for the placementTransform 
            };
            if (xform) {
                options.placementTransform = xform;
            }
            if (offset) {
                options.globalOffset = offset;
            }
            viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewable, options)
                .then(resolve)
                .catch(reject);
        }
        function onDocumentLoadFailure(code) {
            reject(`Could not load document (${code}).`);
        }
        Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load('urn:' + urn, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
    });
}
```

ref: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/multi-model-refresher

Comment: Thank You for your answer. But unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. I can't open multiple views by urn, because they have the same urn.

Comment: I need some advice on how to return more than one endpoint.

Comment: In this way, I can return two endpoints
```Autodesk.Viewing.endpoint.getItemApi = (
          endpoint,
          derivativeUrn,
          api,
        ) => {
          if (svf_path_2 !== null) {
            Autodesk.Viewing.endpoint.getItemApi = (
              endpoint,
              derivativeUrn,
              api,
            ) => {
              return svf_path_2;
            };
          }
          return svf_path_1;
        };
```